CMake library with dependent apps
CMake: build app and dependent library
(Forgive me if this is a duplicate, but I'm not seeing answers for the case where the library is my own work in progress, rather than an established package.)
I wrote a C++ library. I wrote several apps that depend upon that library. The library and some of those apps may one day be published to the open source world. The library is still under development.
Here's the directory structure I would like to use:
    Programs
   /    |    \
Lib   AppA  AppB ...

Here's the logic I want to use: if I build in directory AppA, it builds Lib if out of date, and then builds AppA (but does nothing about AppB). Similarly if I'm in AppB.
I don't want to view Programs as a project to be built in its own right, but only as an overarching collection.
I have read instructions on how to do this if the library code is mixed up in AppA or is in a subdirectory of it, but I don't want that. So what is the best way to structure the various CMakeLists.txt files for my situation? Is it wise to use add_subdirectory if it's not actually a subdirectory, but a sibling? (I haven't yet decided if the library will be static or shared, and I'm curious if it actually makes a difference for these purposes.)

" I don't want to view Programs as a project to be built in its own right" - If you don't make Programs project to be buildable, then just do not organize it so. In CMake a directory don't need to be a project. "... but I'm not seeing answers for the case where the library is my own work in progress, rather than an established package." - I don't see which specific adds "in progress" state of your library. Technically, I don't quite understand your problem at all. Could you provide more details? Preferably with code.

The point of "in progress" is that I am debugging the apps and the library together. So I want my app build to build the library if any of its source files have been updated. (True for each app). Quite different from the case where I just downloaded somebody else's library from a github project and depend on it but I have no intentions of working on it or debugging into it.
I don't have code because I was looking for advice up front. I need a major restructuring of the mess I’ve got.  I think I really want to add_subdirectory to a sibling, does this work?

"I really want to add_subdirectory to a sibling, does this work?" - Sure, why not? You may even call add_subdirectory from App for include Lib. In that case you just need to pass the second parameter-build directory.
